# Firefox - Allowing about: protocol

Tags: firefox, protocol

i have custom ( new tab page ) and one of the feature i want to add to it is a button that send me to about:debugging or about:profiles tabs

when using a hyper link or create a new tab with `url: "about:debugging"`

it gives me this error

> Content at http://127.0.0.1:5500/html.html may not load or link to about:debugging

(ignore `http://127.0.0.1:5500/html.html` it's just for testing)

the same error fire when trying to open `file://...` as a hyper link too

when searching for solution i found out that you can fix the `file://...`  problem by adding this codes to `user.js` or manual to `about:config`

```js
user_pref("capability.policy.policynames", "localfilelinks");
user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.sites", "...");
user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.checkloaduri.enabled", "allAccess");
```

after adding these codes to `about:config` the hyper link for `fill://...` worked well

but i can't figure out the codes for `about:debugging` or any `about page`

i want a flag to stop the security for `moz-extension://88f48502-ba3c-4974-bd91-64fb956e54c6/index.html` to allow it to send me to `about:...` directly

Comment: In your homepage? Do you mean the page that opens each time you open your browser, or a personal webpage? Are pages like about:config not working in Firefox? Can you spend a bit of time explaining further what the core issue is here, the issue that has led you to believe this is the solution to it?

Comment: the new page or the page that open when opening the browser but its a custom version of ( nightTab ) not the default firefox one

Comment: sorry if the question wasn't clear enough hope this edits helps

Comment: That information really needs to be in the question. Your issue may not be related to Firefox, but to your custom plugin.